# Dstore Memory filter returns empty data unless applying .forEach

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid, dstore

I have a "dstore/Memory" object declared like so:

```
this.flightStore = new Memory({
    data: flights,
    idProperty: 'myId'
});
```

I want to get back a filtered collection to display. So I write this:

```
var test = this.flightStore.filter({matchType:view});
```

That returns a 'test' object but the 'data' field is null. Yet when I write identical code but add on a forEach function:

```
this.flightStore.filter({matchType:view}).forEach(function(flight) { ... }
```

This works perfectly and I get back my filtered results one-by-one. From there I can build an array for my filtered collection. I'm curious though as to why my first line doesn't work and if there is a way to get it to work without having to loop through every single result and manually build my array.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try using query option on the store?

Comment: dstore's Memory doesn't support 'query', only dojo/store/Memory.

Answer (score 0):

The `filter` method only applies a filter, it does not fetch data. The `forEach` method fetches data and applies the callback to it. If you want to fetch the data after applying a filter, call `fetch`:

```js
var dataPromise = this.flightStore.filter({matchType: view}).fetch();
```

If you are using a synchronous store (`dstore/Memory`) the `fetchSync` method is available:

```js
var testData = this.flightStore.filter({matchType: view}).fetchSync();
```